# Methods Supporting Seleneium-Webdriver / Ruby

Tags: ruby, methods, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

After hands on `Selenium-Client` and `Watir` I have started working on `Selenium-Webdriver` / `Ruby`.

However I am not getting any information of the Methods and frequently I am getting stuck in my scripts. Like setting an option in drop down is one of the example. I am not able to get all the elements of webpage.

Frequently I am getting errors like `method not found`

Can any one help me out by providing the updated list of methods for `Selenium-Webdriver` with `Ruby`.

I tried to find relevant information on Net and Forums. This [URL](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/Element.html#==-instance_method) contains the Methods however they are also giving the same Error.

Comment: Please post the code you used.

Comment: Below are the examples in which I tried to select the option from drop list. None of them worked giving error as : Method not found.

I have installed selenium-webdriver 2.21.2 gem; Ruby: rubyinstaller-1.8.7-p358

1. @selenium.get_select_options "css=div#idDropList_ixProject_oDropList"

2. @selenium.select("css=div#idDropList_ixProject_oDropList *:nth-child(1)","AYAH")

Also the highlight method which is working fine in selenium-client is not working for webdriver.
@selenium.highlight("xpath=/html/body/div[9]/div[2]")

Comment: The Rdoc for webdriver is also pointing toward the selenium-client methods only.

Comment: While I understand the general problem you are having, it is sometimes easier to get help if you can post the error from a specific code sample. Do you have any you can post? I'd recommend creating a new question with some specific coding issue. Good luck!

Comment: Check out http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RubyBindings
A lot of the backwards compatibility with Selenium-Client is not straightforward, but that page goes over some of it.

Answer (score 0):

I am using selenium webdriver for Automation with Ruby. A [very good website](http://rubyonwindows.blogspot.co.uk/search/label/ruby) is this with lots of info, especially on the use of Excel (automation) together with Ruby. I'm afraid you have chosen the hard way as C# & Java have lots of info and Ruby you need to scavenge the net as resources are limited. Stack overflow has lots of nice examples as well and as Kevin mentioned; it is much easier when you search for a specific error. If I was you I will download a very useful Firefox add-on called Firebug which can be used in conjunction with Selenium IDE. These 2 are very powerful tools that will help tackle most of the things you are getting stuck, at least web-page wise.

[Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) you can use it to inspect any element in a web-page (just right click) and then you can instruct the webdriver to find it via id, link, css or xpath. Xpath is the best when there is no id or css tag. Alternatively what I do when I really get stuck; is to fire up [Selenium IDE](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/) (record & play) and record the action I want (i.e. choose a value from a drop down menu). Then I export the file into a Ruby script grabbing -only- the code that I need (xpath usually) from there.

Hope that helped. Please post any specific error that is still giving you a hard time and we can take it from there. After you download Firebug, right click the drop box that you want to select and post here the results of the inspect element function. Then I can possibly be of further help on how to select it properly.

Just to give you an idea the xpath should look something like the line below..:

```
 element = driver.find_element(:xpath, "//input[@name='payment']")
```

Input is the name of the tag obviously . Then you can locate your element by its internal attributes like..: value, name or even type. The above line will put the result of this '**element**' search into the variable element. You can miss the '**element =**' bit if you are not interested in assigning a variable. However after you find everything you need to locate elements you will realise that you will also need (especially if you are working on automation) a way to control your error handling as web-driver will time-out or crash when it cannot locate an element that has not been already loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't even tell if anyone's pointed to this documentation yet?

http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/index.html